# Sampling distribution from a parametric curve?

Tags: distributions, sample, nonparametric

I'm not sure if this question is well-founded, given that it seems to be mixing random and deterministic processes, but I'm wondering if there's a meaningful answer. Suppose we have a parametric curve in time, for example an exponential rise and decay given by:

[image]

Now say we sample this curve at some rate Δt over some time interval T, and make a density plot of the resulting values. Is it possible to describe the shape of the density with a probability distribution, and if so what would it be? For what it's worth, I'm more interested in something like a truncated power-law curve, but the exponential is an easy example to visualize.

The context for this is trying to connect deterministic models for some physical time series with the statistical measurements of the measured values. Something like the mean should be easy, since you can measure the average value of the function (multiplying with some kind of comb function to model sampling). The standard deviation (and therefore variance) should also be easy, since you can compute the root-mean-square of the function minus its mean. It seems like this should generalize to all moments, which would then (in most nice cases) define your probability distribution.

Comment: What do you mean by "sample this curve at some rate $\Delta t$"? If this means computing $f(0),f(\Delta t),f(2\Delta t),...$ there is no randomness involved.

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, that's what I mean. And I know there's no randomness involved, hence the first sentence of my question. But as I said, you can still compute values that correspond to statistical moments, which makes me wonder if you could associate the sampled values with a probability distribution despite them not actually being random.

Comment: This is straightforward because we can take $t$ to be a uniform random variable on the interval $T,$ so just plug in the usual transformation formula for a transformation.  However, you need to formulate the question you are actually interested in, Ben, because the nature and difficulty of the solution depend inherently on the detailed nature of $f.$  With the exponential you have given there is no analytical solution for most combinations of $\tau_r$ and $\tau_d.$  The problem is going to be a little complicated in any event because $f$ is not one-to-one.